# Zend optimiser - Incompatible file format

Tags: php, zend-optimizer, hostmonster

I have an error while running my website which coded with PHP and uses zend optimiser on hostmonster shared hosting.

The issue appeared since I updated from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4.

Now when I try to use 5.2 the error is

> "Zend Optimizer" is not installed on the Web Server and therefore cannot service encoded files

On PHP 5.4  the error is

> Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 65535, whereas the Loader expects 5 in /home1/mylingui/public_html/admin/config/ProjectConfig.php on line 0

**php.ini**

```
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_extension=/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so
zend_extension=/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I was able to figure out from the Zend forums, your file is encoded for the PHP 5.2 version of Zend Encoder. You need to ask your vendor for a version encoded for PHP 5.4

(http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=112658)

HTH,

=C=

Manager of Training for Zend